Integrability of $z^{\alpha-1}$ in the complex case
This question is based on the discussion on p. 231 of Stein and Shakarchi's complex analysis textbook.
Let $0 < \alpha < 2$ and let $f(z) = z^{\alpha}$ be defined on the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$. Then $$z^{\alpha} = \alpha\int_{0}^{z} w^{\alpha-1}\:\text{d}w$$ where the integral is taken along any piecewise differentiable path (which is the only kind of curve considered in the book) in $\mathbb{H}$ joining $0$ and $z$. The authors explicitly state that $w^{\alpha-1}$ is integrable near $0$ since $\alpha-1 > -1$. If this were a real integral then the result is clear using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (integrating from $\varepsilon$ to $z$) and the Monotone Convergence Theorem (taking $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$). However, I am having trouble proving it in the complex case.
My attempt: Let $\gamma: [0, 1]\rightarrow\mathbb{H}\cup\{0\}$ be a $C^{1}$ curve such that $\gamma(0) = 0$, $\gamma(t) = z$ and $\gamma((0, 1])\subseteq\mathbb{H}$. If we write $\gamma(t) = R(t)e^{i\theta(t)}$ then we can at least ensure that $R$ and $\theta$ are $C^{1}$ on $(0, 1]$. Then $$\int_{0}^{1}|\gamma(t)^{\alpha-1}|\cdot|\gamma'(t)|\:\text{d}t = \int_{0}^{1}R(t)^{\alpha-1}\sqrt{(R'(t))^{2}+(R(t))^2(\theta'(t))^{2}}\:\text{d}t.$$ However, I am stuck at this point since $R'$ and $\theta'$ need not be well behaved near the origin. Any help is appreciated.

Usually it is demanded that the curves on which you integrate are (piecewise) continuously differentiable. A pathological case where, I don't know, $R'$ looks like the Weierstrass function, would be excluded from consideration. At the least they should be bounded.

Even if $R'$ and $\theta'$ are well-behaved, we end up estimating an integral of the form $\int_{0}^{1}R(t)^{\alpha-1}|R'(t)|:\text{d}t$. The natural thing to do would be a change of variables to obtain an integral of the form $\int x^{\alpha-1}:\text{d}x$. But this need not be valid since $R$ is not necessarily monotonic near $0$. How would one deal with this?

The only way we can make sense of this integral is to interpret it as $$\lim_{z_{0}\rightarrow 0;\:z_{0}\in \overline{\mathbb{H}}\setminus\{0\}}\int_{z_{0}}^{z}w^{\alpha-1}\:\text{d}w$$ where the integral is computed along any curve whose image lies in $\overline{\mathbb{H}}$. We must show that this limit is well-defined in the sense that it does not matter how $z_{0}$ approaches $0$ and that it is also independent of the chosen curve. By Cauchy's theorem, it suffices to show that the integral along a circular arc centered at $0$ vanishes as the arc gets smaller. But this is clear since $$\int_{\theta_{0}}^{\theta_{1}}(re^{i\theta})^{\alpha-1}ire^{i\theta}\:\text{d}\theta\rightarrow 0 $$
as $r\rightarrow 0$.
